# In what situations is it convenient to use an expo:publish to update my app or release a new version?

Tags: android, react-native

I've been wondering when it's reasonable to use expo:publish or release a new version.

the question, I have an app in the playstore and they asked me to make some small changes, for example (remove certain images and upload a pdf where those images would be).

in this kind of situation is it enough to use an expo:publish or should I release a new version?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to release a new version as Google Play Console doesn't allow an .aib file when the version is unchanged... Update your version under expo{} and versionCode under android{} in app.json

```
    {
      "expo": {
        "version": "1.0.5",//Increase this to like 1.0.6
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/",
        "backgroundColor" : "#1c1c1c",
        "updates": {
          "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
        },
      "android": {
        "package" : "com.app",
        "versionCode": 6,//Increase this to example 7
        "permissions": ["ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"],
        "config" : {},
    }
```